# How to make multiple ifs code better

Tags: python

Being given the following code I wonder how can I make it better, without using variable valid, yet check ALL the cases and if at least one of them matches set the returned value to False

```
  def validate_ticketer_issue(self, ticketer_issue):
      """
      Validate ticket system issue for common rules
      :param ticketer_issue: (str) ticket system issue key
      :return: (bool) True if issue is successfuly validated
      """
      valid = True
      issues_not_allowed = ('Pool', 'Document', 'Declaration', 'Restriction', 'Pre-Check')
      issues_not_allowed_inprod = ('Analysis', 'Test')

      try:
          issue = self.service.issue(ticketer_issue)
          if len(issue.fields.versions) == 0:  # Affects Version/s
              valid = False
              print('{}: Affects Version/s field is empty'.format(ticketer_issue))

          if issue.fields.issuetype.name in issues_not_allowed:
              valid = False
              print('{}: According to working model commit is not'                        
                    ' allowed to the ticket system issue types'
                    '{}'.format(issue['key'], issues_not_allowed))

          if issue.fields.issuetype.name in issues_not_allowed_inprod:
              valid = False                             
              print('{}: According to working model commit' 
                    ' to the ticket system {} issue types'
                    ' is not allowed in production code'.format(
                        issues_not_allowed_inprod, issue['key']))

          if issue.fields.issuetype.name == 'Fault':
              if not self.validate_fault_issue_summary(issue):
                  valid = False

      except ticketer.exceptions.TicketerError:
          valid = False
          print('{}: issue does NOT exist in the ticket system!'.format(ticketer_issue))

      if valid:
          print('{}: OK'.format(ticketer_issue))

      return valid
```

Comment: code review will suit better. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you should ask this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you are right, thank you!

Comment: @mastier Just to be clear, is this your code?

Comment: @Kaz yes, it is,
Already made Code Review, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154992/how-to-make-multiple-ifs-code-better
I think this might be closed